# Why do Shuls put up notices saying משנכנס אדר מרבים בשמחה?

Tags: purim, synagogue, simchah-joy-happiness

Why do Shuls put up notices saying משנכנס אדר מרבים בשמחה ?

Do we think that a notice will change our mood? And if so, why not put up a notice in Elul saying that the Yom HaDin is coming?

Comment: what about mishenichnas av signs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Nitei Gavriel - Purim Perek 11 #4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46446&st=&pgnum=98) brings from the Yalkut Avraham Siman 686, that the Minhag was to put the משנכנס sign over the Zecher L'Charban area, since it is a Zeman Simcha.

Regarding hanging a [Mishenechnas sign in the Shul](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/pardes/pardes18.pdf) - see page 262 - that the Minhag was to hang it on the Western wall of the Shul - where often that is where the entrance is.

Why we do not hang up in Elul signs - the שו"ת אפרקסתא דעניא ח"ב או"ח סי' לו ס"ק ד says that since there is no such Maamar Chazal therefore we do not do it.

Comment: that's a great source!

Comment: Thanks, @GershonGold. I don't know people who do it in the house. We don't have a zecher l'churban in our Shul (that I know of).

Comment: My parents always hung a Mishenechnas Adar sign in their house and I do so too.

Comment: Thanks again, @GershonGold for the updated answer; complete, convincing and generating simcha!

Comment: @Gershon Gold Putting up the mishenichnas sign over the zecher lechurban area fits well with the source כשם שמשנכנס אב ממעטין בשמחה כך משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה (Taanis 29a)